# Let $X$ be non-empty open convex. Is $X_n := \{x \in \mathbb R^d \mid \inf_{y \in X^c} |x-y| \ge 1/n\}$ convex?

Tags: convex-geometry

In solving [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4483475/how-to-extend-a-theorem-about-hausdorff-dimension-of-the-non-differentiability-s) question, I have come up with the following result.

> **Theorem:** Let $X  \subset \mathbb R^d$ be non-empty open convex. There is a sequence $(X_n)$ of closed convex subsets of $X$ such that $X_n \nearrow X$, i.e., $X_n \subset X$ and $\bigcup_n X_n = X$.

**My attempt:** Let
$$
X_n := \{x \in \mathbb R^d \mid \inf_{y \in X^c} |x-y| \ge 1/n\} \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N^*.
$$

Clearly, $X_n \subset X_{n+1} \subset X$. Let $(x_m) \subset X_n$ such that $x_m \to a \in \mathbb R^d$. Then
$$
\inf_{y \in X^c} |a-y| \ge \inf_{y \in X^c} [|x_m-y|-|x_m-a|] = \left [ \inf_{y \in X^c} |x_m-y| \right ] - |x_m-a| \ge \frac{1}{n} - |x_m-a|.
$$

It follows that
$$
\inf_{y \in X^c} |a-y| \ge  \frac{1}{n} - \lim_m|x_m-a| = \frac{1}{n}.
$$

Hence $a \in X_n$, and thus $X_n$ is closed. Let $a \in X$. Then $\inf_{y \in X^c} |a-y| >0$ because $X^c$ is closed. Then $a \in X_n$ for sufficiently large $n$. Hence $\bigcup_n X_n = X$.

Let $a,b \in X_n$ and $\lambda \in (0, 1)$. Let $c := \lambda a + (1-\lambda)b$. We have
$$
\inf_{y \in X^c} |a-y| \ge  \frac{1}{n} \quad \text{and} \quad \inf_{y \in X^c} |b-y| \ge  \frac{1}{n}.
$$

We want to prove that $c \in X_n$.

---

In my attempt, I'm stuck at proving that $X_n$ is convex. Could you elaborate on how to proceed?

---

**Update:** Let $Y_n := \{x \in \mathbb R^d \mid |x| \le n\}$. Then $Y_n$ is closed convex. Let $Z_n := X_n \cap Y_n$. Then $(Z_n)$ is a sequence of bounded closed convex subsets of $X$ such that $Z_n \nearrow X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth considering the following characterization of the points from $X_n$:
$$ x\in X_n\iff B\left(x,\frac 1n\right)\subset X \iff \forall(v\in B(0,1/n)):x+v\in X.$$ Consider $a,b\in X_n$ and $\lambda\in(0,1)$. Let $c := \lambda a + (1-\lambda)b$ and $y\in B(c,1/n)$. Then $y=c+v$ where $v\in B(0,1/n)$. Then
$$y=c+v=\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b+v = \lambda (a+v) + (1-\lambda)(b+v).\tag{*}$$ Since $a,b\in X_n$, we have $a+v,b+v\in X$. Therefore from (*) and the convexity of $X$ we have $y\in X$. This shows that $B(c,1/n)\subset X$, therefore $c\in X_n$.

Comment: Nice explanation : $+1 $